# Within the mobile/ios Photoshop App, can I, 1) access the edits history and, if so, 2) Can I then delete select step(s) in the middle of history?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, image-editing, mobile, ios

In working primarily with the mobile Photoshop app in ios, I’m occasionally wanting to delete an edit (e.g. eraser tool) that I made 5-10 minutes ago. I’d like do this without first having to delete all the edits made after that step - which is what I’m currently doing, using the “undo” arrow (and then having to remember and recreate those edits). It can add a lot of time to my workflow.

Does Photoshop for ios allow access to the edits history and will it allow the deletion of specific edits without deleting all edits that were made after that edit?

Comment: What you are seeking is **non-linear history**. The desktop app has it via the History Panel, I don't know about the mobile app.

Answer (score -1):

Below, in quotes, is the best answer that I could find regarding this question but:

- the answer appears to pertain to the desktop version of Photoshop only (at least ios/mobile is not specified) and,
- one comment to this answer states that they tried pjk_ok’s solution but it did not work.

“Despite the answers here saying otherwise, yes you can delete one step in your history.

You do this by selecting the fly-out menu button in the history panel then doing History Options > Allow Non-linear History. Then you can delete any step in your history without it deleting any subsequents steps after it.

It's a real shame this answer has over 6k views stating you can't do this.

answered Jan 10, 2021 at 2:15
pjk_ok”

Comment: Yes, but can you do it on the iOS app? That is what the OP is asking. Many apps for mobile devices don't have the full functionality of the equivalent desktop applications. If the information you found is only for the desktop application, then it's not really answering the question.

Comment: @Ircam12 When quoting external sources, please provide a link to the original source in your answer. See [Referencing](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) in the [Help] for more info.